# Minify typescript files using Grunt

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, minify, grunt-contrib-uglify, gruntfile

I wanted to minify typescript files in my angular app.I tried by giving grunt command in my Gruntfile.js as

```
  uglify:{

            ts:{
                src:['test/scripts/**/*.ts'],
                dest:'test/scripts/**/*.ts'
            },

            js:{
                src:['test/scripts/hr.js'],
                dest:'test/scripts/hr.js'
            }
        }
```

When I ran the command `grunt uglify` The js files were uglified but not the ts files.How can I minify ts files?

Comment: You will want to uglify the `.js` files AFTER they have been compiled to JavaScript. This makes it a two step process if you use grunt to compile your TypeScript.

Comment: @Martin .So I can't directly minify/uglify the typescript  files.

Comment: No you cannot. And if you could, why would you want to? No one should ever see the TypeScript besides the developers who are reading and writing the TypeScript. TypeScript is your source code, it will never be sent to the browser. JavaScript is your object code that is sent to the browser and run in the browsers JavaScript VM (or on a server running NodeJS). JavaScript sent to the browser SHOULD be uglified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the way you should write your gruntfile:

```
grunt.initConfig({

  pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

  typescript: {
    base: {
        src:['test/scripts/**/tsfile.ts'],
            dest:'test/scripts/**/tsfile.js'
        options: {
            sourcemap: true,
            declaration: false
        }
    }
  },

  uglify: {
    dist: {
        files: {
            'test/scripts/**/tsfile.min.js': ['test/scripts/**/tsfile.js'],
            'test/scripts/hr.js' : ['test/scripts/hr.js']
        }
    }
  }

});
```

Comment: Hi Saba.Thanks for the answer.What if I have two files in diffferent location s and I want to minify the same ?

Comment: Do you want to compile both into one or seperately?

Comment: Compile both separately

Comment: You can specify the source and destination paths in files object.

`files : { dest1 : [source1], dest2 : [source2], ...}`